# The return value of the function is not displayed in the placeholder attribute

Tags: javascript, function, date

I took up to finalize an existing project. in it js lies immediately in the html document and works properly. When I try to move the js to a separate file, the return value of the function is not displayed in the placeholder attribute. Who can tell me what is wrong?

**this is how it was displayed before**

```
                    <input id="MyDate2" name="d1" size="19">
                    <!-- <script>
                        var dt=new Date();
                        var month = dt.getMonth()+1;
                        if (month<10) { month='0'+month; }
                        var hour=dt.getHours();
                        if (hour<7){
                            var day = dt.getDate()-1;
                        }
                        else {
                            var day = dt.getDate();
                        }
                        if (day<10) { day='0'+day; }
                        var year = dt.getFullYear();
                        MyDate2.value=year+'-'+month+'-'+day+' 07:00:00';
                    </script> -->
```

**this is what I tried to implement**

```
"use strict";

function getDate(date) {
    date = new Date();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
    }
    let hour = date.getHours();
    if (hour < 7) {
        let day = date.getDate() - 1;
    } else {
        let day = date.getDate();
    }
    if (day < 10) {
        day = '0' + day;
    }
    let year = date.getFullYear();

    return date.placeholder = `${year}-${month}-${day}-${hour}`;
}

let MyDate2 = document.getElementById("MyDate2");
getDate(MyDate2);
```

Comment: you're reusing the variable with `date = new Date();`. It's no longer the element that was passed as an argument. Use a different variable name.